# What Chinese font should i use in my CSS for Android 4.4?

Tags: android, html, css, fonts

I am using below CSS in my code. But I'm not sure if Android 4.4 have "Microsoft Yahei" font. Which exact chinese font should i specify in my CSS?

```
body {
    font-family: Roboto,Arial,Helvetica,"Microsoft yahei","微软雅黑","微軟正黑體Microsoft JhengHei","微軟正黑體 Microsoft JhengHei","Microsoft JhengHei","微軟正黑體",sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Fount it. Its noto sans.

Answer (score 0):

I believe its Noto Sans but for future reference font are stored under `/system/fonts` in your android directory if you need to look it up.